# JavaScript to get all sites i'm follwing?

Tags: 2013, javascript

I'm looking for a way to get all the sites I'm following by using JavaScript. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use REST API to get the followed sites.

Below is the REST endpoint

```
GET http://<siteCollection>/<site>/_api/social.following/my/followedsitesuri
```

you can get more details on below MSDN link
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn194080.aspx

Comment: I also found below codeplex solution for this: https://iamfollowing.codeplex.com/

Comment: Thanks, but I found this one is a better URL `http://<siteCollection>/<site>_api/social.following/my/followed(types=4)`

Comment: @jlai79 how is that endpoint better? I can understand by reading Amit's answer what the endpoint should return...

Comment: @John-M Amit's MSDN link gives the answer: My/FollowedSitesUri Gets the URI to the Sites I'm following page for the current user, My/Followed Gets ... sites ... that the current user is following.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved using JSOM as well.

```
function getAllFavorites() {
        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var followingManager = new 
              SP.Social.SocialFollowingManager(clientContext);
        var documents = new SP.Social.SocialActorInfo();
        documents = followingManager.getFollowed(15);

       /*15 is to get users, documents, sites and tags that the logged
        in user is following. For more details
        https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj667835.aspx */

        var actorTypes = ['User', 'Document', 'Site', 'Tag'];

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function() {
           documents.forEach(function (doc, i) {
                    var item = {};
                    item.Name = doc.get_name();
                    item.actorType = actorTypes[doc.get_actorType()];
                    item.url = doc.get_uri();
                    $scope.favorites.push(item);
                });                               
        }, function(sender, args) {
            alert("Error: " + args.get_message());
        });
    }

SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('userprofile', 
'SP.Social.SocialFollowingManager', function () {
   getAllFavorites();

/*This is to make sure the methods SP.ClientContext and 
SP.Social.SocialFollowingManager are loaded for the method
to work */

});
});
```